# Ambiguous Layout - presenting one ViewController from another

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout, ambiguous

I am doing the following upon 'button click' from my initial view controller and getting Ambiguous Layout.

```
[self presentViewController:vcSecond animated:YES completion: nil];
```

vcSecond is instantiated programmatically as follows

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

//[sb instantiateInitialViewController]; 

SecondViewController *vcSecond = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SecondViewControllerStoryboardId"];
```

After the second view is on the screen, checking for ambiguous layout:

```
(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]

*<UIWindow:0x16580870> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   *<UIView:0x166239c0>
|   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0x16696500> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0x16643620> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
(lldb)
```

The second view has absolutely no elements, just a blank view. There is no ambiguous layout when the Initial View is up (and before the button is clicked to bring the Second View Controller).

I am using Auto Layout. Set in the Storyboard.

I going around in circles. Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the statement, [sb instantiateInitialViewController], supposed to be doing? Is SecondViewController the initial view controller in sb? If so, you're instantiating it twice.

Comment: [sb instantiateInitialViewController]; is not required actually. Its the result of copy paste leftover. I removed it. Second view controller is not Initial View controller in sb. I am trying to present the second view controller from the initial view controller.